# Charging a LiPo Battery with 1.5V Battery

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, boost

I have a lithium-polymer battery with a voltage of 11.4V. If I want to charge it with a 1.5V power source (AA battery) and I boost the voltage to 11.7V will it slowly charge the LiPo.

Comment: which battery do you know the capacity and SoC of each pack? and understand the losses?

Comment: One thing to note is also that you can't just apply a voltage to LiPo batteries.  You should charge them only with a circuit specifically designed to do so, and you should use them only with overvoltage, undervoltage and overcurrent protection provided by the charge/discharge circuit.  If you treat lithium rechargeables poorly they tend to expand and possibly damage their device, or even start on fire.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 the lipo would be about half charged and 1.5V battery would be fully charged.

Comment: @KH the charging would be at max .1amps and would be brief. Is there any risk of damage doing it that way?

Comment: Maximum charge current would be determined by the Lipo battery type and the internal resistance of the AA GA1battery.  To put 1A into the Lipo you would have to draw ~8A or more from the AA which is not going to be possible.  You can either purchase or design a charging circuit, but either way it should be designed for the battery type you wish to charge and also with the source in mind.  If you simply try to pull as much current as possible from a AA, you will greatly decrease effective battery life.